# Factory pattern for creating embossing machines

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, interface

I'm working on a program that creates a file for a specific embosser machine (machine that creates plastic bank card for example). I have 3 embosser machines and all of them create different files. Every file contains a card number, last and first name, address, etc. The difference between the files is that they contain specific characters for the delimiter.

I want to implement this project with a factory pattern.

For simplicity sake, let's say that I have these embossers: `DataCard`, `CIM` and `DataCard2`.

This is how I created the files in my project, and I'd like to know if this is a good way of doing it.

```
public enum eEmbosserType
{
    Datacard,
    Cim,
    Datacard2
}

public interface IEmbosser
{
    eEmbosserType EmbosserType { get; }

    List<EmbosserData> Data { get; set; }

    void CreateFileForEmbosser(string path);

    void PrepareDataForEmboser();
}

   public class DataCardEmbosser : Emboser.IEmbosser
{

    public eEmbosserType EmbosserType => eEmbosserType.Datacard;

    public List<EmbosserData> Data { get ; set; }

    public void CreateFileForEmbosser(string path)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
        {

            foreach (DataCard item in Data)
            {

                sw.Write(item.cardNumber + "_!");
                sw.Write(item.city + "_?");
                sw.Write(item.name + "_^");
                sw.Write(item.expDate + "_:");

            }

        }
    }

    public void PrepareDataForEmboser()
    {
        Data = new List<EmbosserData>();

        List<CardData> cards = GetCardData();

        foreach (CardData card in cards)
        {

            DataCard dc = new DataCard();

            dc.cardNumber = card.PAN;
            dc.city = card.City;
            dc.expDate = card.Expire;
            dc.name = card.Owner;

            Data.Add(dc);

        }

    }
}

public class CimEmbosser : Emboser.IEmbosser
{
    public eEmbosserType EmbosserType => eEmbosserType.Datacard2;

    public List<EmbosserData> Data { get; set; }

    public void CreateFileForEmbosser(string path)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
        {

            foreach (Cim item in Data)
            {

                sw.Write(item.cardNumber + ";");
                sw.Write(item.city + ";");
                sw.Write(item.name + ";");
                sw.Write(item.expDate + ";");
                sw.Write(item.version + ";");

            }

        }
    }

    public void PrepareDataForEmboser()
    {
        Data = new List<EmbosserData>();

        List<CardData> cards = GetCardData();

        foreach (CardData card in cards)
        {

            Cim dc = new Cim();

            dc.cardNumber = card.PAN;
            dc.city = card.City;
            dc.expDate = card.Expire;
            dc.name = card.Owner;
            dc.version = DateTime.Now.ToString() + GetNewVersionNumber();

            Data.Add(dc);

        }
    }
}

public class DataCard2Embosser : Emboser.IEmbosser
{
    public eEmbosserType EmbosserType => eEmbosserType.Datacard2;

    public List<EmbosserData> Data { get; set; }

    public void CreateFileForEmbosser(string path)
    {

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
        {

            foreach (DataCard2 item in Data)
            {

                sw.Write(item.cardNumber + ";_");
                sw.Write(item.city + "?");
                sw.Write(item.name + ";");
                sw.Write(item.expDate + "#");
                sw.Write(item.f1 + " ");
                sw.Write(item.f2 + " ");
                sw.Write(item.f3 + " ");

            }

        }

    }

    public void PrepareDataForEmboser()
    {
        Data = new List<EmboserData>();

        List<CardData> cards = GetCardData();

        foreach (CardData card in cards)
        {

            DataCard2 dc = new DataCard2();

            dc.cardNumber = card.PAN;
            dc.city = card.City;
            dc.expDate = card.Expire;
            dc.name = card.Owner;
            dc.f1 = card.PAN + " " + card.Expire;
            dc.f2 = card.Owner + " " + card.Address;
            dc.f3 = cards.Count().ToString().Trim();

            Data.Add(dc);

        }
    }
}
```

And factory creator

```
public class EmbosserCreator
{
    public static IEmbosser GetEmboser(eEmbosserType type)
    {

        switch (type)
        {
            case eEmbosserType.Datacard:
                return new DataCardEmbosser();
            case eEmbosserType.Cim:
                return new CimEmbosser();
            case eEmbosserType.Datacard2:
                return new DataCard2Embosser();
            default:
                throw new Exception("");
        }
    }
}
```

For data I thought I should create an abstract class, `EmbosserData`, which inherits classes `DataCard`, `CIM`, and `DataCard2`.

For example:

```
public abstract class EmbosserData
{
    public string cardNumber { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string expDate { get; set; }
}

public class DataCard : EmbosserData
{

}

public class Cim : EmbosserData
{
    public string version { get; set; }
}

public class DataCard2 : EmbosserData
{
    public string f1 { get; set; }
    public string f2 { get; set; }
    public string f3 { get; set; }
}
```

Is this a good approach for my project? If you have any advice for other implementations, I'd love to know more.

PS. I hope that code is now ok to understand my idea.

Comment: Please visit our help center to see how to ask a question that is on-topic for this site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Hypothetical identifiers _A, B, C_ are discouraged. Could you post your real working code instead?

Comment: Real working code contains my mother language, so you would confuse if you read.

Comment: See [this meta question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3795/should-code-be-forcibly-translated-into-english) for some comments concerning translations. We require working (and not stub) code because otherwise the OP ends up with many completely useless reviews, and miss out on the context-sensitive useful stuff.

Comment: This is looking much better, but can you include the definitions of `DataCard` and `DataCard2`? Again, stub code simple isn't worth posting, because it can't be usefully reviewed.

Comment: DataCard is machine with old standard and DataCard2 is machine with newer standard, difference between them is that newer standard has F1, F2 and F3 fields, and bit different delimiters in file according to DataCard old standard.

Comment: Where is `GetCardData` defined?

Comment: GetCardData is method that reads data from database with SqlDataReader and returns list of objects CardData.

Comment: Could you show us how this will be used? It would help to see if it's a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

#### `eEmbosserType`

- Don't use Hungarian Notation in C#. A better name would be `EmbosserType` or `EmbosserKind`.

#### `IEmbosser`

- This is a public interface, so I would expect that consumers could make their own implementations. If this is allowed, consumers are hampered by `EmbosserType` because this enum is under your control. Consider using an external key like `string` if more types are allowed.
- Next up are methods `CreateFileForEmbosser`, `PrepareDataForEmboser` and a mutable property `Data`. These are 3 separate concerns: IO, data lookup and in-memory data storage. This might be a bit too much for a single interface to handle. I feel these concerns are sufficiently independant to warrant separate interfaces to allow better *reusability*, *granularity* and *modularity*. Consider splitting into interfaces `IDataRepository` (db or any other data source access), `IDataProvider` (store the data in-memory with a read-only getter) and `IDataWriter` (write data to a stream).
- I have a few problems with method `PrepareDataForEmboser` since it's void and takes no parameters. Implementations only have the name of the method to decide what to do, and what is expected of them to do. From your implementatons I reverse engineered (should have documentation instead) that this method expects `Data` to be set. An additional problem here is that this property is mutable, allowing consumers to bypass the method and store `Data` directly, rendering your method unguarded and the design insufficiently encapsulated. Furthermore, implementations have to fetch the data `GetCardData` and store it internally, which is also mixing two different concerns.
- Method `CreateFileForEmbosser` is very specific that it needs to write to the system. I would change the specification to allow to write to a `Stream` instead. This way, consumers are free to provide the type of stream to write to, a file, a string builder, or any other stream.

#### `class *Embosser`

- I have questions about this design where each concrete instance fetches base class `EmbosserData` data using `GetCardData`, while iterating over concrete (for instance `DataCard`) data. I would have expected a base class to provide method `GetCardData` and perhaps also a generic type parameter for the return type.

#### `EmbosserCreator`

- In the initial revision of your question, you called this an *Abstract Factory Pattern*. Note, this is just a *Factory Pattern*. The former pattern is a factory for factories.
- Exception information might be a bit too cryptic for consumers and end-users: `throw new Exception("");`.

---

#### Conclusion

In general, I'm not sure why you need a factory for these different embossers, since each of them work with different data classes (probably also different data sources) and different data serialisation. Your question does not show us how you would use this pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your review, after your comments I think I messed with design, maybe it is better to use just abstract class `Embosser` instead interface.
And all classes that inherits `Embosser` class override methods `CreateFileForEmbosser`, `PrepareDataForEmboser`

Method GetCardData fetch data from only one table, and from that data I create object of class `DataCard2`, `CIM` and `DataCard`.